# How do I use input values to format dimension of edited data frame in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I copied an interesting piece of code to generate some editable data frames in Shiny (reproduced hereafter).

It allows to edit a 10 rows data frame.
In the code, I have added a numeric input that may be accessed in the server shiny function through *input$NI*. I wish to customize the number of rows of the editable data frame using this numeric input.

I first thought I could replace the *10* in *add_row(x = rep(0,10),y = rep(0,10))* by *input$NI* but this solution obviously doesn't work.

Any help would be welcome,
Marc

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Editable Dataframe and Plot"),

  # Main panel
  mainPanel(
    numericInput( "NI" ,
                  "Numeric input -- number of row", min = 3 ,value = 5 , max = 9 ),
          DTOutput("my_datatable")
    ),
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  #initialize a blank dataframe
  v <- reactiveValues(data = {
    data.frame(x = numeric(0),y = numeric(0)) %>%
      add_row(x = rep(0,10),y = rep(0,10))
  })

  #output the datatable based on the dataframe (and make it editable)
  output$my_datatable <- renderDT({
    DT::datatable(v$data, editable = TRUE)
  })

  #when there is any edit to a cell, write that edit to the initial dataframe
  #check to make sure it's positive, if not convert
  observeEvent(input$my_datatable_cell_edit, {
    #get values
    info = input$my_datatable_cell_edit
    i = as.numeric(info$row)
    j = as.numeric(info$col)
    k = as.numeric(info$value)
    if(k < 0){ #convert to positive if negative
      k <- k * -1
    }

    #write values to reactive
    v$data[i,j] <- k
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
observe({
    v$data <- data.frame(x = numeric(0),y = numeric(0)) %>%
      add_row(x = rep(0,input$NI),y = rep(0,input$NI))
  })
```

Comment: Though I still don't understand the logic behind, It worked.
Thanks a lot.